# Why does Spark's OneHotEncoder drop the last category by default?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, one-hot-encoding, bigdata

I would like to understand the rational behind the Spark's OneHotEncoder dropping the last category by default.

For example:

```
>>> fd = spark.createDataFrame( [(1.0, "a"), (1.5, "a"), (10.0, "b"), (3.2, "c")], ["x","c"])
>>> ss = StringIndexer(inputCol="c",outputCol="c_idx")
>>> ff = ss.fit(fd).transform(fd)
>>> ff.show()
+----+---+-----+
|   x|  c|c_idx|
+----+---+-----+
| 1.0|  a|  0.0|
| 1.5|  a|  0.0|
|10.0|  b|  1.0|
| 3.2|  c|  2.0|
+----+---+-----+
```

By default, the OneHotEncoder will drop the last category:

```
>>> oe = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="c_idx",outputCol="c_idx_vec")
>>> fe = oe.transform(ff)
>>> fe.show()
+----+---+-----+-------------+
|   x|  c|c_idx|    c_idx_vec|
+----+---+-----+-------------+
| 1.0|  a|  0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
| 1.5|  a|  0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
|10.0|  b|  1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|
| 3.2|  c|  2.0|    (2,[],[])|
+----+---+-----+-------------+
```

Of course, this behavior can be changed:

```
>>> oe.setDropLast(False)
>>> fl = oe.transform(ff)
>>> fl.show()
+----+---+-----+-------------+
|   x|  c|c_idx|    c_idx_vec|
+----+---+-----+-------------+
| 1.0|  a|  0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])|
| 1.5|  a|  0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])|
|10.0|  b|  1.0|(3,[1],[1.0])|
| 3.2|  c|  2.0|(3,[2],[1.0])|
+----+---+-----+-------------+
```

**Question::**

- In what case is the default behavior desirable?
- What issues might be overlooked by blindly calling `setDropLast(False)`?
- What do the authors mean by the following statment in the documentation?

> The last category is not included by default (configurable via dropLast) because it makes the vector entries sum up to one, and hence linearly dependent.

Comment: I would recommend you to search for literature/articles about the `dummy variable trap` (and linear regression).

Comment: @Aeck Thanks! Looks like the dummy variable trap is definitely the answer to this question, if someone cared to write a little about it...

Comment: @Corey Had related a problem where I was confused by not even knowing that dropping the last category was even a thing. Posted and answered a question about it that includes a bit more about the *dummy variable trap (DVT)* here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51604166/8236733. But basically, ... dropping the last cat. value is done to avoid a DVT where one input variable can be predicted from the others (eg. don't need a 1hot encoding of `[isBoy, isGirl]` when an encoding `[isBoy]` would give the same info). The solution to the DVT is to drop one (not necessarily the last) of the cat. variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the doc it is to keep the column independents:

> A one-hot encoder that maps a column of category indices to a column
> of binary vectors, with at most a single one-value per row that
> indicates the input category index. For example with 5 categories, an
> input value of 2.0 would map to an output vector of [0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
> 0.0]. The last category is not included by default (configurable via OneHotEncoder!.dropLast because it makes the vector entries sum up to
> one, and hence linearly dependent. So an input value of 4.0 maps to
> [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]. Note that this is different from scikit-learn's
> OneHotEncoder, which keeps all categories. The output vectors are
> sparse.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: Haha, points for being the least lazy and willing to write *something*. In case someone looks up this answer, here's some more info. The categorical features lead to effective intercepts. If you include a general intercept term, then the minimizer could add e.g. 0.5 to the intercept and -0.5 to all categories to get the same value of the cost function. To avoid this degeneracy, remove the intercept and include all categories.

Comment: Adding to this: 
For Scala api, use `.setFitIntercept(false)` on the logistic regression classifier to remove the intercept when including all categories!

Comment: So you answered a question by quoting the same piece of text that was already in the question.

Comment: @Corey, I think that the main take from this should be "be aware to this". To be on the safe side I'd suggest considering this in the model selection phase.